# Removing the substring

Tags: powershell

Trying to remove the substring in between the braces in powershell.

```
$name = "Kothuru, Manoj Kumar (Happy)"
$name = "Manoj Kumar"
$name = "Manoj (end)"
```

I tried the below code by splitting the string by braces.

```
$name.Split("(")[0]
```

Is there any better way to do this. Since if the name doesn't contain the tail. It won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Replacement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#replacement-operator). It has the following syntax.

```
<input> -replace <regular-expression>, <substitute>
```

Use `\(.*?\)` pattern to match the characters between the parentheses and replace it with empty string.

```
$name -replace "\(.*?\)", ""
```